# How to hide Images after animation end in android

Tags: java, android

In my android application I have five imageviews when I click any one of that all images are animating. I set the zoomout and Zoomin animation for all the images. once the animation is finished, the selected image view is invisible. After image invisible, when i click on that imageview  location it again start the animation and the image is invisible.

**Zoom-In Animation:**

```
<scale  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromXScale="1" 
  android:toXScale="5" 
  android:fromYScale="1" 
  android:toYScale="5" 
  android:pivotX="50%" 
  android:pivotY="50%" 
  android:duration="1000" 
  android:fillAfter="true">
</scale>
```

**Zoom-out Animation**

```
<scale  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromXScale="5" 
  android:toXScale="1" 
  android:fromYScale="5" 
  android:toYScale="1" 
  android:pivotX="50%" 
  android:pivotY="50%" 
  android:duration="1000" 
  android:fillAfter="true">
</scale>

 zoomin =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom);
 zoomout=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,  R.anim.zoomout);

 ImageView v2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);

     v2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
       @Override public void onClick(View v) 
       {

          v2.setAnimation(zoomin);
          v2.startAnimation(zoomin);
          v2.setAnimation(zoomout);
          v2.startAnimation(zoomout);
          v2.clearAnimation();
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this code to your animation objects:

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
            {
                v2.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_transparent_image);

            }
        });
```

Comment: he mentioned that if he click the location of that image after got disappear it has to appear again and animate.?by ur solution if the visibility gone how the action can be performed again?

Comment: You can do whatever you like in the onAnimationEnd. Maybe try to replace the background to a transparent on if you want the image to still be clickable.

Comment: Yes thats should be the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is occuring because you added 
        android:fillAfter="true" 
in both Animation XML files.

Either remove "android:fillAfter="true" from both XMLs or keep "       android:fillAfter="false" in both files.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply change the transparency of the layer.

```
v2.setAlpha(0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to handle the animation listener for that animation.

```
zoomin.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
        {               
            v2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a **Transparent Image** 
All you need to do is when your Animation ends you need to set a transparent Image as background/scr of that image thereby replacing the previous one.

Changing the **visibility** of view **won't solve** your problem

```
 v2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 v2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

As both above lead to make your view non-clickable and you won't be able to click again.

Answer (score 0):

You must first thing use image.clearAnimation() then hide it
image.visibility = View.GONE