# How to make an ImageView invisible after it animates in Android

Tags: android, animation

I animated an ImageView to move across the screen, but I want it to turn invisible when it finishes animating (to make it seem like it went off the screen).

This is the code that I tried:

```
translate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
 @Override
 public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
 button.setText("Animation Started");


 }

 @Override
 public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
     brickimg.setVisibility(View.GONE);//This should make the ImageView invisible 

 }

 @Override
 public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

 }
 });
```

However, the animation never ends. It's stuck on AnimationStart, so the only thing that happens in this case is that the button's text gets changed. Does anyone know how to make the animation end, or just make the ImageView turn invisible after it finishes animating?

EDIT - This was the code I used to make the animation:

```
int x=brickimg.getRight()-brickimg.getLeft();
   int y=brickimg.getBottom()-brickimg.getTop();
   final TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(
           Animation.ABSOLUTE,1000, Animation.ABSOLUTE,
           x, Animation.ABSOLUTE,0,
           Animation.ABSOLUTE,y);//How far it goes on the axis. The first x goes left, second x goes right, first y goes up, second goes down
   translate.setDuration(300);//speed of the animation
   translate.setFillEnabled(true);
   translate.setFillAfter(true); 
  brickimg.startAnimation(translate);
```

Comment: have you checked, your_animation.setRepeatCount(0); ?

Comment: You can also refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921968/how-to-hide-images-after-animation-end-in-android

Comment: Can you also share the code where other attributes of translate animation are set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set transparent image on AnimationEnd..

```
  @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
        {
            v2.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_transparent_image);

        }
```

Comment: Issue is not about hiding the imageView. The problem stated in the Question is animation is looping infinite.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what kind of animation you are doing.If you are using [View Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) class.Then the animations that you create is done not on the initial image.For example,translation animation on an image from point A to point B creates the aforementioned animation.But the your original image is still stuck in the same place. ie at Point A.It will go back there once the animation is over.If you want animations which affect the ImageView,you need use the more customizable and harder to implement [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).If your question was merely about making the view invisible then your approach should have worked.Or else go through these docs once